# Making image view disapear and re appear over the view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello Im having trouble with my image view. i have a login view controller and i have a UIButton when clicked an image view animates across the view controller which is this:

```
- (IBAction)alreadyUser:(id)sender {
    [_usnernameField resignFirstResponder];
    [_passwordField resignFirstResponder];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{_loginOverlayView.frame = self.view.frame;

     }];
}
```

but i can’t figure out how to undo this action i tried `[_loginOverlayView setHidden:YES];` 
but then it states hidden when i try to come back to it

Comment: Try setting hidden to no in the animation or just before the animation.  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{[_loginOverlayView setHidden:NO]; _loginOverlayView.frame = self.view.frame; }];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appear:

```
[_loginOverlayView setHidden:NO];
```

Disappear:

```
[_loginOverlayView setHidden:YES];
```

you can put before or after the animation to hide or show the loginOverlayView.